# Configuring issue when install a version of Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, debian

RVM is installed and running. I am trying to install Ruby 2.0, but this happens with any version I try to install. This is a fresh install of rvm without ruby. I am running Debian Squeeze.

After running

```
rvm install 2.0
```

I get this error:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
    ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
    ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /home/user/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0 (already extracted)
    ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    Error running './configure --prefix=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
    please read /home/user/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log
    There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I see this error when I read /home/user/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log

```
checking if make is GNU make... ./configure: line 18790: make: command
not found no checking for safe null command for make... configure:
error: no candidate for safe null command
```

I then run:

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=4 --debug
```

Then I get this error

```
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring... Error running './configure
--prefix=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared', please read /home/user/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /home/user/.rvm/tmp/26623*
```

I am not sure what to do after this point

Comment: Do you have `make` installed?

Comment: it looks like a bug, open a ticket for RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: I installed 'make' and reinstalled rvm with ruby and it works. Thank you I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally for certain gems you will probably also need

```
apt-get install build-essential
```